# One user can have multiple messages in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to create a one to many relationship between a User table and a Message table using Hibernate. One User can have multiple messages in the message database. But, I am not able to get the schema for it.
Here is my code

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    User user;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany
    Message message;

    public User(String userName, String password) {
        this.username = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Message.java

```
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String content;

    @Type(type="timestamp")
    private Date created;

    public Message() {

    }

    public Message(String sender, String receiver, String content) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.content = content;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

This is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE `Message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `receiver` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_jreodf78a7pl5qidfh43axdfb` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

But unfortunately, I am unable to get the one to many relationship for the user and messages. Can anyone help me do it please. How to design a schema to get the one to many relationship and how to change the POJO classes to achieve it?

Comment: How exactly are you not being able to the get the relationship? Do you have any console errors or anything that can give us a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing the `OneToMany` relation the wrong way, you are supposed to use a `Collection` of messages in your `User` Entity

```
@OneToMany
private List<Messages> messages;  // Or Set<>
```

Comment: Also, I don't get what is point of adding another reference to the user in the `User` class itself, `@ManyToOne User user;`, I guess you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a ManyToOne decorator in the message class that points to user.

```
@ManyToOne
public User getUser() { return user; }
public void setUser(User user) { this.user = user; }
private User user;
```

And remove the @OneToMany from User